# Найти вершину треугольника

Tags: математика, алгоритм

```
Добрый день.
Необходимо на форме отрисовать равнобедренный треугольник. На входе дано только координаты вершин, что определяют основу треугольника и суму длин двух других сторон.
В тех случаях, когда основа параллельна одной из осей проблем нету.
Уже час не могу придумать как определить координаты третьей вершины когда она не параллельна.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть `A`, `B` -- вершины основания, `C` -- неизвестная вершина. Если дана сумма `s` длин боковых сторон, то каждая из сторон равна половине этой суммы. Итак, `AC = BC = s/2`.

Пусть `M` -- середина `AB` (её координаты равны полусумме координат `A` и `B`). Тогда `CM` -- высота, из прямоугольного треугольника `AMC` имеем:

```
CM = sqrt(AC^2 - AM^2) = sqrt(s^2/4 - AB^2/4)
```

(Если под корнем отрицательное число, задача, очевидно, не имеет решений.)

Итак, у нас есть длина вектора `MC`, его направление найти несложно, учитывая, что он перпендикулярен вектору `AB`: если `(p, q)` -- вектор `AB`, то вектор `(-q, p)` перпендикулярен ему, вектор `(-q/l, p/l)` (где `l = sqrt(p^2 + q^2)`) перпендикулярен `AB` и имеет длину 1, а вектор `(-q/l*L, p/l*L)` (где `L` -- рассчитанная раньше длина `CM`) перпендикулярен `AB` и имеет длину, равную длине `MC`.

Таким образом, у нас есть вектор `MC`. Прибавляя его координаты к координатам точки `M`, мы получаем точку `C`.

[image: то же самое графически]

Заметьте, что у нас возможно 2 решения, отличающиеся знаком вектора `MC`: для получения второго решения поменяйте знак у `MC` из первого решения.

Эта и другие подобные задачи будут кодироваться очень легко, если в вашем арсенале есть классы, представляющие точку, вектор, и определены операции над ними. Например, в моём коде обычно решение выглядит так (C#):

```
var AB = B - A;
var M = A + AB * 0.5;
var L = Math.Sqrt(s * s - AB.Length * AB.Length) / 2;
var MC = AB.Rotate(Angle.FromDegrees(90)).GetUnitVector() * L;
var C1 = M + MC;
var C2 = M + (-MC);
```

Comment: Чем рисовали картинку, если не секрет?

Comment: @Flammable: (посыпая голову пеплом) обыкновенный Paint.NET :(

Comment: Я-то было подумал...

Comment: Ну Paint.NET -- не ms paint, но с xfig на таких работах ему всё равно не тягаться.

Comment: @alexlz: а он под форточками бывает?

Comment: Под cygwin'ом вроде сам собирал, но это было лет десять (или чуть меньше назад). Может уже в дистрибутиве cygwin'а есть. Для native windows есть какой-то WinFIG, но я с ним не связывался. Когда ставил xfig/cygwin, WinFIG денежку хотел, сейчас -- не знаю.

Интеграция с TeX/LaTeX у него красивая. И преобразования картинки в текст на tcl/tk и java (transig) тоже прикалывает.

Comment: @alexlz: мне стало интересно, попробовал программу GeoGebra, вроде ничего: http://www.geogebratube.org/student/m30845

Comment: Страшное дело. firefox говорит: "Нужно установить плагин". Жму на кнопку "установить" -- он по новой. Что это за сайт?

В общем напугал он меня, запретил я ему javascript... Стрёмный какой-то сайт.

Comment: @alexlz: Там нужна java. Вроде у меня никаких вирусов не запустилось (хотя я обычно держу ненужные плагины, в т. ч. и java, отключёнными). На сайте интерактивный чертёж.

Comment: Спасибо, не хочу.

Comment: @alexlz: ну бог с ним, не так уж и важно.

Answer (score 1):

написать систему уравнений окружности

```
  (x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2=R

  (x-x01)^2+(y-y01)^2=R
```

(где x и y это координаты третьей точки)(где x0 y0 x01 y01 координаты двух известных вершин), 
но как ты решил когда основание параллельна одной из осей если в любом случае получается два возможных варианта решения задачи.Третья точка может быть сверху или снизу основания.

Comment: Спасибо! Там не имеет значения какую из двух точек брать.

Comment: не за что)

Comment: @Freest, отметьте ответ принятым, если он подошел.

Comment: Справа в формулах R^2.